# Get UID URL for ALAsset with ALAssetPropertyAssetURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

I get asset URL by calling [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL] sometimes it returns nil or may be asset is nil (I've seen it in the crash logs). 
I've read in the documentation:

```
ALAssetPropertyAssetURL
The key to retrieve a URL identifier for the asset.

The corresponding value is an NSURL object.

This URL is used by the library-change notifications to identify assets and asset groups. Only the ALAssetRepresentation and ALAssetsGroup classes support this property.
```

I think it is mean, that I can't get ALAssetPropertyAssetURL property from ALAsset, but it works any time when I run it.

Questions:

2. How I can get Asset url to use it in [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs: ....]?

**UPD**

I don't understand this: "How to get URL  if only the ALAssetRepresentation and ALAssetsGroup classes support this property?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use something like this with `ALAsset` object

```
[[asset defaultRepresentation] url]
```

Comment: Sorry, but this method will be deprecated in the future ios.

Comment: Yes. we'll have to use PhotosLibrary instead of AssetsLibrary

Comment: You have to use PHAsset instead.